# Remove Alpha Channel from Picture

Tags: javascript, signaturepad

Is it possible to get an Picture via "export" function without transparent pixels? (e.g. white background).

Comment: yes, use any <canvas> based image tool, like a resizer. you can "resize" to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); did the trick. 
Thank you for your suggestions.